# Accurate PG database size for comparing representations

Tags: postgresql, performance, jdbc, performance-tuning

I have a Java/JDBC program that takes a sample file and imports the data into the database, shredding it across multiple relations. The program does this multiple times for several different representations, one of which uses Large Objects. I can share more details of these representations but they are quite long and aren't relevant to this question since I'm looking for something generic.

I would like to compare the sizes of these different representations by examining the size of the database after each import. The database is on a PostgreSQL 9.4 local Windows server instance, with no other users and default configuration. Its only purpose is to conduct this test.

My initial plan was as follows:

```
for each representation {
  call VACUUM ANALYZE
  record old DB size with SELECT pg_tablespace_size('pg_default');
  import data into database
  call VACUUM ANALYZE
  record new DB size with SELECT pg_tablespace_size('pg_default');
  store storage cost as new DB size - old DB size
}
```

Obviously there are limitations to this approach, but my expectation is that for large files (~100MB) the reported storage costs should be reasonable approximations. Note that I use `pg_tablespace_size` in order to include the contribution of data outside of the main schema, such as large objects (in `pg_catalog.pg_largeobject` and `pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata`).

I'm wondering whether this is a correct approach, and whether there is a better approach. I'm unsure whether `VACUUM ANALYZE` properly updates the stats used by `pg_tablespace_size`, even though it is called in the same session. It would also be better if I could avoid calling `VACUUM ANALYZE`, since this requires connecting as the superuser in order to run on the `pg_catalog` relations.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call `pg_database_size(dbname)` to know the size of the database.

`VACUUM` (without the `FULL` clause) does not free any space, it only marks it as reusable, and thus will not change the database's size (except in a rare boundary case, see [Routine Vacuuming](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html)).

`ANALYZE` does statistical sampling and would be useful if you needed the row counts, but for the global db size, it's not necessary.